# How do you make a 'docset' that you can use for Dash app?

Tags: documentation-generation, docset

I have been googling this for like 2 hours now and i cannot figure it out.

I want to make a docset out of the [GitHub CLI Manual](https://cli.github.com/manual/) so i can access it locally on my mac using Dash app (or DevDocs app for that matter).

Also ditto for the [WordPress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/).

Can anyone help me understand what this process is?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Official documentation on docset generation can be found [here](https://kapeli.com/docsets#dashDocset)
Basically you acquire docs in a form of a directory with locally viewable web-content and covert it with provided tools. Good luck!